# In the dopesheet, setting a new keyframe between two existing keyframes overwrites keyframe data

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

I'm a technical artist at an indie game studio.

Actually, this is an issue that one of our artists is having, and he screenshared his process with me over Google Hangouts. This is what I observed:

1. He would set the beginning (A) and and end (B) keyframes for a
   3-key idle cycle.
2. When creating the middle keyframe (C), he would select a single
   channel in the dopesheet editor and a single object in 3D View.
3. The transform values applied when setting keyframe C would also be
   expressed in keyframe B.
4. This was confirmed both while posing and while playing the animation
   (Alt + A).

The strange part is that I couldn't reproduce this behavior when I tested the .blend file on my end. The artist also noted that this was the first time he had encountered the behavior, as he'd successfully produced 15 animations for our project earlier this year without issue.

We haven't found any similar issues when searching Google, which leads me to believe it is a setting somewhere which allows the user to overwrite keyframes which are already set later in the timeline. Feel free to comment with any suggestions of human error, as well.

A few final notes:

- I am using Blender 2.67 while our artist is using 2.69.
- I am on a Mac while he's using Windows.
- We are testing a file which the artist created and shared with me via Dropbox.

Thanks in advance for your help. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intended or undefined behaviour. Try raising a report at developer.blender.org.